# Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Method 'Fragment' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.CSharpHelper'

Tags: c#, .net-7.0, health-check, ef-core-7.0

I have .NET 7 microservices using the following nuget packages :

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 7.0.8
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 7.0.8
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 7.0.8
```

I implemented health check based on the details shared at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-7.0

For health check I used the following nuget packages :

```
AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI 6.0.5
AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.Client 6.0.5
AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.InMemory.Storage 6.0.5
```

I am also using scrutor version : 4.2.2 to manage the automation of dependency injection

Now on running the application I got the following error :

```
Unhandled exception
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Method 'Fragment' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.CSharpHelper' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, Version=6.0.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
   at Scrutor.TypeSourceSelector.<>c.<InternalFromAssemblies>b__24_0(Assembly asm)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Scrutor.LifetimeSelector.Scrutor.ISelector.Populate(IServiceCollection services, RegistrationStrategy strategy)
   at Scrutor.ServiceTypeSelector.Scrutor.ISelector.Populate(IServiceCollection services, RegistrationStrategy registrationStrategy)
   at Scrutor.ImplementationTypeSelector.Scrutor.ISelector.Populate(IServiceCollection services, RegistrationStrategy registrationStrategy)
   at Scrutor.TypeSourceSelector.Populate(IServiceCollection services, RegistrationStrategy registrationStrategy)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.Populate(IServiceCollection services, ISelector selector, RegistrationStrategy registrationStrategy)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.Scan(IServiceCollection services, Action`1 action)
```

Based on the above error I installed the nuget package :

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 7.0.8
```

Now when I try to run the application I see the following error :

```
Unhandled exception
System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.RelationalEntityTypeAnnotations' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=7.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.RelationalModelAnnotations' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=7.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.RelationalPropertyAnnotations' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=7.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
Could not load type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.RelationalFullAnnotationNames' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational, Version=7.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
   at Scrutor.TypeSourceSelector.<>c.<InternalFromAssemblies>b__24_0(Assembly asm)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectManySingleSelectorIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.SelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at Scrutor.LifetimeSelector.Scrutor.ISelector.Populate(IServiceCollection services, RegistrationStrategy strategy)
   at Scrutor.ServiceTypeSelector.Scrutor.ISelector.Populate(IServiceCollection services, RegistrationStrategy registrationStrategy)
   at Scrutor.ImplementationTypeSelector.Scrutor.ISelector.Populate(IServiceCollection services, RegistrationStrategy registrationStrategy)
   at Scrutor.TypeSourceSelector.Populate(IServiceCollection services, RegistrationStrategy registrationStrategy)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.Populate(IServiceCollection services, ISelector selector, RegistrationStrategy registrationStrategy)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions.Scan(IServiceCollection services, Action`1 action)
```

If I remove the below nuget packages , I can run the application successfully without any issues.

```
AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI 6.0.5
AspNetCore.HealthChecks.UI.InMemory.Storage 6.0.5
```

Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance